# react-three-fiber 360 image darker than the original image

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to create a 360 image using react-three-fiber. The 360 viewer is working perfectly as it purposed but the generated image is darker than the original image.

Here's the screenshot from my 360 viewer
[image]

Here's the original image
[image]

Here's my code

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { useTexture, OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

const Generate360Image = (props) => {

  var myTexture = useTexture(props.imageLocation);

  return (
    <>
      <mesh
        position={[0, 0, 0]}
      >
        <sphereGeometry attach="geometry" args={[500, 60, 60]} />
        <meshBasicMaterial
          attach="material"
          map={myTexture}
          side={THREE.DoubleSide}
        />
      </mesh>
    </>
  );
};

class GenerateImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Canvas style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Generate360Image
            imageLocation={this.props.myImage}
            className="image-canvas"
          />
        </Suspense>
        <OrbitControls
          autoRotate="true"
          autoRotateSpeed={0.4}
          minDistance={5}
          maxDistance={80}
        />
      </Canvas>
    );
  }
}

export default GenerateImage;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try use `meshPhysicalMaterial` instead of `meshBasicMaterial`. `meshBasicMaterial` does not properly reflect lightings.

compare these two samples from three.js docs

- [meshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=meshbasicmaterial#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial)
- [meshPhysicalMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=meshphysi#api/en/materials/MeshPhysicalMaterial)